# Retry mechanism for Selenium Java tests on Jenkins to handle intermittent failures

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I have a set of Selenium Java tests that I run on Jenkins, and I'm experiencing intermittent failures on the Jenkins environment, even though the same tests pass consistently when executed locally. I suspect these failures are caused by factors such as slow remote machines or random timeouts.

I'll get reports on an element not appearing, simply due to the website not loading on time, so timeouts are frequent. They don't happen too often though.

To address this issue, I would like to implement a retry mechanism for these tests in order to increase their reliability on Jenkins. Ideally, I would like the tests to automatically retry until they pass, or at most, retry a maximum of three times. It seems that a simple retry often results in a successful execution on the subsequent attempt. Important thing to note that about 80% of the tests pass all the time, but the remaining 20% will fail, randomly, no specific tests.

Is there a recommended approach or best practice for implementing such a retry mechanism in Selenium Java tests on Jenkins? Are there any libraries, frameworks, or specific techniques that can be leveraged to achieve this goal?

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code examples that can help me address this intermittent test failure issue on Jenkins. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I'm using TestNG.

Edit:

I created a new pipeline item that goes as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'ant compile'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                retry(3) {
                    sh 'ant runTests'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run it, it finishes in 2 seconds, successfully, without actually doing anything. I'm assuming I'm missing some stuff related to the actual repository of my tests, basically, the pipeline has no idea what to run. So, how do I connect my pipeline to the build that's running my tests?

Comment: Your description is not clear. Are the tests in a different job that you are trying to trigger?

Comment: Yes they are. @M B

Comment: What does your build trigger look like? Have you specified that the pipeline should wait until the downstream build finishes before continuing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go looking for any external libraries or frameworks because Jenkins has an inbuilt `retry` keyword ([doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times)).

```
stage ('selenium-tests') {
    retry(3) {
        <tests>
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a problem, I think I'm halfway through